# Redirect python output to file

Tags: python, bash

I have the following code in `bash script`

```
python -u - << EOF
from my.package import script
script.run()
EOF
>> /path/to/log/file
```

In `script.py` there are a number of `print statements` and I would like to redirect that output from the console to a file.  The file gets created successfully, but it's empty.

How can I go about this? What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you able to update the actual python file?

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45817397/5291015) work? If so, do read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is right, but the way you re-direct the output to a file from here-document is wrong, Heredocs themselves re-directs just like any other commands, just do

```
python -u - << EOF >> /path/to/log/file
from my.package import script
script.run()
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import sys
f = open("log_file.txt", 'w')
sys.stdout = f
print "My print statements"
f.close()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Right syntax is:

```
python -u - >> /path/to/log/file << EOF
from my.package import script
script.run()
EOF
```

The reason is that if you write in bash something like that:

```
util_1 | util_2 | util_3 >> some_file < another_file
```

or

```
util_1 | util_2 | util_3 >> some_file << EOF
...
EOF
```

`another_file` or here-document goes to the standard input of the first utility in pipeline (in this case to `util_1`).